# Global or static function in python classes?

Tags: python, class, methods

I've got a class that manages a video camera and file stream. Each instance of the class is a frame that has a bunch of methods, attributes, etc. I'm doing all the initialization outside a function so it happens once and sets a few variables that are global to all instances of the class. Those global variables include Video and File objects that i need to close properly at shutdown from my main program.

I'm newish to Python and mostly Java/C/C++ background and I remember having functions that were associated with the class that i could call that accessed global (static) class variables. Can i do something similar in Python?

Here is my pseudo code for my class:

```
class MyClass:
      global_variable = 1
      openFile = file.open()

      def someMethod( self ):
          do stuff 

      def cleanUpStuff():
            self.openFile.release()
```

Now in my main program I need to call cleanUpStuff() to close out my camera and files properly. I'm creating hundreds of instances of MyClass objects that I use and get destroyed by the garbage collection at some point. So i need a way to call at the Class level.

```
    while True:
       a = MyClass()
       a.someMethod()

       if something:
          break  
    MyClass.cleanUpStuff()
```

Comment: Have a look at the [classmethod](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#classmethod) decorator.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to John this appears to work exactly like i want. I didn't know about "decorators" so i have no idea why this works exactly but that is a path i can follow now at least i've solved this problem...

```
@classmethod
def cleanUpStuff( MyClass ):
   MyClass.openFile.release()
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).